# How to remove "padding" on left side of R markdown generated HTML file

Tags: r, r-markdown

When opening a "wide" .html file generated with R Markdown (example .rmd file code below), there is a large bit of white space on the left side when the file is opened in a browser (but not in an R view window), that causes unnecessary "scrolling" to the right. How can I get rid of this space?

````
---
title: "Yucky 'Padding' on Left"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r echo = FALSE, warning= FALSE, message=FALSE}
 library(markdown)
 library(kableExtra)
 library(DT)

funStuff <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:600,ncol=30))
datatable(funStuff)

``` end
````

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me and justifying my HTML output on the left:

```
---
title: "Background Info"
date: "November 24, 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    toc: no
---
<style>
.main-container {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: this removes everything?

Comment: @Thorst You need to add </style> after the CSS part to close the Style sheet.

Comment: Seems like this one should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is related to the use of `datatable` in a html output, which is too wide because of the high number of columns, then you may want to look at `datatable` option `scrollX`.

````
---
title: "Yucky 'Padding' on Left"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r echo = FALSE, warning= FALSE, message=FALSE}
 library(markdown)
 library(kableExtra)
 library(DT)

funStuff <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:600,ncol=30))
datatable(funStuff, 
          options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

``` 
end
````

Note that this work only for HTML outputs.